# Possible to Set Initial Array to Returned Nested Objects

Tags: reactjs

I have some fetched data that returns an array of objects, each with a nested array of objects. The nested array I have mentioned, `blog_comments`, can have a value dynamically inserted from a form on my page and I have a parent-child function that handles the POST and array insertion, but I can't seem to figure out a way to set the array initially to each of the `blog_comments` objects. Is there a way to do a nested map and set the objects with `setState`? Should this be handled in the constructor of my stateful component? componentDidMount?

**JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "blogId": 105,
    "blogDateSlug": "08\/15\/2017",
    "title": "Working Hard",
    "discovery": "lorem ipsum",
    "created_at": "2017-08-15T23:23:50.329Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-08-15T23:25:23.826Z",
    "blog_user": {
      "fullNameSlug": "Mike Rellis",
      "firstName": "Mike",
      "lastName": "Rellis",
      "picture": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/certain-web-assets/user-example-two.jpg"
    },
    "blog_comments": [
      {
        "createdAtDateSlug": "8\/15\/2017 11:10 AM",
        "comment": "Great work with this article",
        "created_at": "2017-08-16T10:44:52.492Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-16T10:44:52.492Z",
        "blog_user": {
          "fullNameSlug": "Sandra Matthews",
          "firstName": "Sandra",
          "lastName": "Matthews",
          "picture": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/certain-web-assets/user-example-one.jpg"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Here is my data fetch:**

```
class BlogFeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {blogs: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ blogs: data.blog, user: data.user, csrf: data.csrfToken });
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BlogFeed {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

**Here is the loop skeleton that will return the correct object I'm trying to set to my `comments` state array:**

```
this.props.blogs.map((blog, index) => {
    { this.props.blog_comments.map((comment, i) => {

    })
})
```

**Here is the component handling the array insertion and should handle the initial array state:**

```
class BlogFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            comments: []
        };
        this.updateCommentsFunc = this.updateCommentsFunc.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.blogs.map((blog) => {
            console.log("setCommentArr() triggered");
            console.log(blog);
        })
    }

    setCommentArr(){

    }


    updateCommentsFunc(newComments){
        console.log("Update Comments Func Triggered");
        var updatedCommentArr = this.state.comments.slice();
        updatedCommentArr.push(newComments)
        this.setState({comments: updatedCommentArr});
        console.log(this.state.comments);
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
            { 
                this.props.blogs.map((blog, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 blog-card">
                                <BlogCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={this.props.user} />
                                <Comments {...blog} key={index} blogId={blog.blogIdHash} csrf={this.props.csrf} updateComments={this.updateCommentsFunc}/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method. Here you can call `this.setState()` on your `BlogFeed` Component in response to changes in `props` after the fetch completes.

What you would pass to `this.setState()` would depend on how you want `comments` represented in the Component state and what you are going to do with that state.

Could be the flattened array of comments:

```
const comments = nextProps.blogs
  .reduce((arr, blog) => arr.concat(blog.blog_comments), []);
```

Or it could be an object of comments keyed to the `blogId`:

```
const comments = nextProps.blogs
  .reduce((obj, blog) => Object.assign(obj, { [blog.blogId]: blog.blog_comments }), {});
```

then just call with the desired state change:

```
this.setState({ comments })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What would be getting passed to `this.setState()` and will I be able to add the `.map` functionality mentioned in my question within this lifecycle method? I've never used this method before and would love to see how the mapping and setting would happen.

Comment: edited the answer to show how the state could be set during the `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle method. Ultimately, it depends your use case, but I would build the state change object, then call `setState()` with that object as an argument.